# Testing Observable based call hierarchy in angular

Tags: unit-testing, angular, typescript, jasmine

I am trying to test a component which uses Observables and then cascades through several function calls when the Observable resolves. Here is a version of the component.

```
export class NotificationComponent implements OnInit {
  private answerSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(public toasterService: ToasterService, private commentService: CommentService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.answerSubscription = this.commentService.answer$.subscribe(
      answer => this.commentComplete(answer));
  }

  commentComplete(answer) {
    this.toasterService.clear(answer.toastId);
    let promptAns = this.search(answer.toastId);
  }    
}
```

and here is my test:

```
class MockToastService {
  clear() {}
 }
class MockCommentService {
  answer$: Observable<any>;
  constructor() {
    this.answer$ = Observable.of({toastId: '123'});
  }
}
describe('NotificationComponent', () => {
  let component: NotificationComponent; let fixture: ComponentFixture<NotificationComponent>;
  let mockComment = new MockCommentService(); let mockToast = new MockToastService();

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [NotificationComponent, MockToast],
      providers: [{ provide: ToasterService, useValue: mockToast },
                  { provide: CommentService, useValue: mockComment }]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NotificationComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should complete notification on answer', () => {
    spyOn(component, 'commentComplete'); spyOn(mockToast, 'clear');
    expect(component.commentComplete).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    component.ngOnInit();
    expect(component.commentComplete).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(mockToast.clear).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

The test passes on `expect(component.commentComplete).toHaveBeenCalled();`, but fails on `expect(mockToast.clear).toHaveBeenCalled()`. As you can see from the component, `toasterService.clear(` should be called straight after `commentComplete`, however, I have stepped through with a debugger, and the test criteria is being checked before the clear function is being called.

I have tried adding `fakeAsync` and `tick()`, but am still facing the issue. Any idea how I can make this test's timing work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use fake Async here but as understand there the issues was not with it.

You fake 'commentComplete' function by spyOn(component,'commentComplete') but you need to spy and do its job. change to 'spyOn(component, 'commentComplete').and.callThrough();'

> Spies: and.callThrough. By chaining the spy with and.callThrough, the spy will still track all calls to it but in addition it will delegate to the actual implementation.

https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html

here is the code that should work:

```
it('should complete notification on answer', fakeAsync(() => {
  const spyComplete = spyOn(component, 'commentComplete').and.callThrough();
  const spyToast = spyOn(mockToast, 'clear');

  expect(component.commentComplete).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  component.ngOnInit();

  tick();

  expect(spyComplete).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(spyToast).toHaveBeenCalled();
}));
```